# addEventListener() does not execute

Tags: javascript, dom, this, addeventlistener

-------------------------------------------- Update: 10mins later ----------------------------------------------------

After going through the comments I think it is needed to give more contxt information of where this problematic method is called.

```
//fetch fake user info from RandomAPI
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=12&nat=us') //pull 12 results
    //parse json
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    //process employee data and return a new employee list
    .then(data => extractEmployeeData(data.results)) 
    //for every employee in the list, generate dom element and bind it to employee object
    .then(employees => employees.map((employee, index) => employee.generateEmployeeCard(main, index)))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

With that said... I don't really know if the bug has anything to do with this async call... maybe you skilled people will find any clue ...

--------------------------------------------------- Original Post --------------------------------------------------------------

I have a class:

```
class Employee {
  this.card;
  this.info = { some employee info... }

  ......

  // generates employee card and binds handler to the dom object generated
  generateEmployeeCard(containerDiv, index) {
      const html = ` some markup... `
      containerDiv.innerHTML += html;
      this.card = document.getElementById(`employee${index}`);

      //THE PROBLEM LINE
      this.card.addEventListener('click', event => this.generateEmployeeModal());
  }

  .......
}
```

Everything works as expected until the last line in `generateEmployeeCard()` method. This line is supposed to add event listener to `this.card' which is a dom element object. But instead this line choose to not do anything when it's executed. I looked at the "Event Listeners" tab RIGHT AFTER the execution of this line, there is nothing. This looks really weird and I couldn't find any similar issue here. Please help and thank you!

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: try changing your arrow function to an anonymous function (`function(event) {...}`)

Comment: I tried use non-arrow function but no luck. it acts like the addEventListener() is not called.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9rbct2na/), as does [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6q7pbtry/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be assigning the event handler directly to the function:

```
this.card.addEventListener("click", this.generateEmployeeModal);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem here seems to be the addEventListener method is never called, so the callback doesn't even exist anywhere after this line is executed.

Comment: Is your script running before your HTML is loaded? Put your script at the bottom of your body, and add a window.onload to make sure that issue is fixed

Comment: I put a breakpoint right on the bugged line. I hovered over `this.card` and the corresponding card div lit up. So `this.card` is what it expected to be... I think I have narrowed it down to just the `addEventListener()` method not firing at all...

Comment: Are you still using your original code? It's possible it could be the arrow function. Try using my code instead.